# Can't receive touch events in custom UIView with XIB

Tags: objective-c, uiview, autolayout, xib, masonry

I have a view controller that contains a scroll view. Inside of the scroll view, I have a custom header view with its own custom NIB. The issue I am having is that touch events on a button inside the custom view are not being fired. From reading other answers, I tried setting my custom view's `clipsToBounds` property to YES, and doing so results in no visible content for the header view. This is probably part of the problem, but I don't know how to fix it. My code below:

In the view controller:

```
@interface MyViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) DetailHeaderView *headerView; // The custom view placed inside contentView
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *contentView; // content view for scrollView
@end

@implementation MyViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Load the Header View
    NSArray *views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DetailHeaderView" owner:nil options:nil];
    self.headerView = [views firstObject];
    self.headerView.psychic = self.psychic;

    // Add the header view to the scroll view
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.headerView];
    [self setConstraints];
}

-(void)setConstraints {
    [self.view removeConstraints:self.view.constraints];
    [self.scrollView removeConstraints:self.scrollView.constraints];
    [self.contentView removeConstraints:self.contentView.constraints];
    [self.headerView removeConstraints:self.headerView.constraints];

    [self.scrollView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.left.equalTo(self.view);
        make.right.equalTo(self.view);
        make.top.equalTo(self.view);
        make.bottom.equalTo(self.view);
    }];

    [self.contentView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.edges.equalTo(self.scrollView);
        make.width.equalTo(self.scrollView);
    }];

    [self.headerView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.top.equalTo(self.contentView);
        make.left.equalTo(self.contentView);
        make.width.equalTo(self.contentView);
        make.height.equalTo(@120);
    }];
}
```

And in my custom view file:

```
@interface DetailHeaderView()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPhotoView *photoView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *levelLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *experienceLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *horizontalRuleView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet StarRatingView *ratingView;
@property BOOL constraintsAlreadySet;
@end

@implementation DetailHeaderView

-(void)updateConstraints {
    [super updateConstraints];
    //    self.clipsToBounds = YES;  <- When I uncomment this, I see nothing.

    [self removeConstraints:self.constraints];


    [self.photoView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.top.equalTo(self).with.offset(20);
        make.left.equalTo(self).with.offset(8);
        make.width.equalTo(@120);
        make.height.equalTo(@100);
    }];
    [self.levelLabel mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.top.equalTo(self.photoView).with.offset(8);
        make.left.equalTo(self.photoView.mas_right).with.offset(8);
    }];

    // self.priceButton below is the button that is not clickable.
    // It is not set as a property in this .m file because it is declared as a 
    // public property in the .h so that the parent view can respond to events.
    [self.priceButton mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.centerY.equalTo(self.levelLabel);
        make.right.equalTo(self).with.offset(-8);
    }];
    [self.horizontalRuleView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.left.equalTo(self.levelLabel);
        make.top.equalTo(self.levelLabel.mas_bottom).with.offset(8);
        make.right.equalTo(self.priceButton);
        make.height.equalTo(@1);
    }];
    [self.experienceLabel mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.top.equalTo(self.horizontalRuleView.mas_bottom).with.offset(8);
        make.left.equalTo(self.horizontalRuleView);
    }];

    [self.ratingView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.top.equalTo(self.experienceLabel.mas_bottom).with.offset(8);
        make.left.equalTo(self.experienceLabel);
    }];
}
```

Again, without setting `clipsToBounds` in "DetailHeaderView", I see all the content, but the `self.priceButton` property does not have touch events sent.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Something in your view hierarchy is preventing touches or else swallowing them. My guess is you need to set userInteractionEnabled=YES on the contentView and/or the headerView.